# Is it possible to call a URL in a Splunk dashboard and get the response as a string?

Tags: splunk

I have a Splunk dashboard where you have a table with selected encoded identifiers.

You can click on a row and select an identifier as a token which fills additional fields with data. Now on the intranet of my company we have a url where you can enter the encoded identifier and get back the decoded data in a GET request.

Right now I have a single-value field which displays the encoded identifier and when you click on it it makes a call to the decoder and opens the decoded result in a new tab. That's a standard Splunk link.

Is it possible to make Splunk call the URL automatically (do a GET request) when the identifier is selected (the token is set) and retrieve the response data as a string and extract (using regex) and display the decoded data automatically in the single value field?

If not, is it at least possible for Splunk to get the response data as a string instead of opening the result in a new tab when you click on the encoded identifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have the drilldown target be an external link.

If that is correct, just put the external URL in the drilldown: [image]

If you want some *value* from an external link to be pulled-into Splunk, then you'll need to setup another mechanism.

For example, you might have a [scripted input](https://www.splunk.com/view/SP-CAAAHUD) that will query an external endpoint, and add results to an index or lookup table.

Or you might utilize a [REST endpoint app](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/apps/#/search/rest) to achieve something similar.

Comment: What I want is indeed the second point. I figured it wouldn't be so simple when I couldn't find simple answers by searching. Thank you for the reply, I will look deeper into the possibilities.